# JavaScript Regular Expression nothing to repeat

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm using the following JavaScript code to create a regular expression to match a UK mobile number:

```
new RegExp("(\+44|0)7\d{9}", 'g');
```

However, I get an error in the console log saying:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: /(?:+44|0)7d{9}/:
>   Nothing to repeat

Similar questions on StackOverflow point to a missing escaped character, but mine seem to be fine.

I have also tried without the `global` flag.

Help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `new RegExp("(?:\\+44|0)7\\d{9}", 'g');`

Comment: @AvinashRaj, that worked! Can you explain why this is the case?

Comment: within double quotes, escape all the backslashes one more time or otherwise it would treat backslash as an escape sequence.

Comment: @AvinashRaj Within *all* string literals. JavaScript/ECMAScript makes no difference between single- and double-quoted strings, unlike e.g. PHP. And the point is that escape sequences *start* with a backslash both in string literals and `RegExp` initialisers (\\ is the escape sequence for the backslash in both literal types). The string literal is evaluated *before* the string value is passed to the `RegExp` constructor. As the other answer says, when there are no variable parts in the expression, use `RegExp` initialisers instead to avoid such errors and make the expression more readable.

Answer (score 0):

You can create RegExp by using short method

```
var a = /(\+44|0)7\d{9}/g
```

Its must works good)