# Nothing to repeat with regexp in Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to replace all occurences of {0}, {1}, {2}, etc in a string with Javascript.

Example string:

```
var str = "Hello, my name is {0} and I'm {1} years.";
```

I'm tried the following to construct the regexp:

```
var regex1 = new RegExp("{" + i + "}", "g")
var regex2 = new RegExp("\{" + i + "\}", "g")
```

Both attempts throws the error:

```
Invalid regular expression: /{0}/: Nothing to repeat
```

I use replace like this:

```
str.replace(regex, "Inserted string");
```

Found all kinds of StackOverflow posts with different solutions, but not quite to solve my case.

Comment: maybe related : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/610406/javascript-equivalent-to-printf-string-format

Comment: This a duplicate of duplicate(s+), e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29120713/javascript-regular-expression-nothing-to-repeat

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The string literal `"\{"` results in the string `"{"`. If you need a backslash in there, you need to escape it:

```
"\\{"
```

This will results in the regex `\{..\}`, which is the correct regex syntax.

Having said that, your approach is more than weird. Using a regex you should do something like this:

```
var substitues = ['foo', 'bar'];
str = str.replace(/\{(\d+)\}/, function (match, num) {
    return substitutes[num];
});
```

In other words, don't dynamically construct a regex for each value; do one regex which matches all values and lets you substitute them as needed.